# Два сайта на одном субдомене. Возможно ли?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, site

Есть сайт на субдомене, на нём уже установлен WordPress, но нужно ещё в этот же субдомен засунуть второй сайт на чистом php. Посоветуйте - возомжно ли и как это реализовать два сайта? Что уже только не перепробовал по статьям, но пока-что не нашёл толкового ответа. Если есть решения - посоветуйте пожалуйста. Буду благодарен.

Comment: WP в одну папку, второй сайт в другую... не вижу проблемы

Comment: @byVerng Дело в том, что создал папку на этом же сайте (WP), залил свой движок и он фактически перестал работать, как бы я его не вертел. Редиректы, подключения к бд, хотя изначально я их уже изменил под данный сайт

Comment: А как вы их предполагаете разносить по url? Что во втором сайте на чистом php - набор своих страниц?

Comment: @KAGGDesign Там набор страниц c редиректами разными. Но проблема в том,что уже всё перепробовал, а толкового ничего не нашёл.

Answer (score 0):

> второй сайт на чистом php.

По умолчанию ВП игнорирует физически существующие файлы и каталоги. Поэтому эти **файлы** работать будут. А вот "сайт" на них *(что есть бред по сути ибо "сайт" - это всё, что на домене)* - уже другой вопрос. Это в немалой степень зависит от правил обработки ЧПУ и др моментов.